# Find x,y position of last line in pdf file - itextsharp

Tags: itext

I want to add an image to a pdf file. the position of the image should be just above the last line in a pdf file.

How do I get the x,y position of the last line in the pdf or the x,y position of the end of the last text block.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an object named `TextMarginFinder` and use it like is done in this Java example: [ShowTextMargins](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15#579-showtextmargins.java)

```
public void addMarginRectangle(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    TextMarginFinder finder;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        finder = parser.processContent(i, new TextMarginFinder());
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        cb.rectangle(finder.getLlx(), finder.getLly(),
            finder.getWidth(), finder.getHeight());
        cb.stroke();
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```